# Object Model for folders and Subfolders in an NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, treeview

I have a datastucture in my app containing folders as a **flat** array structure as the following

```
/FolderA/folderB
/FolderA
/FolderC/folderD
/FolderC
/FolderF
```

and so on. 
I want to use this data as a *datasource* of a structured *NSOutlineView*. Final tree should be represented as the following:

```
/FolderA/
    folderB
/FolderC/
    folderD
/FolderC
/FolderF
```

a classical structured tree view.

Any idea on how to model this ? Keep in mind that my data is already in my application and it is stored in a flat array.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Look into NSTreeController, and setting up your models that represent your nodes with appropriate keyPaths.
Core data example:
http://jonathandann.wordpress.com/2008/05/13/nstreecontroller-and-core-data-sorted/